# Long table in Appendix

Tags: longtable, appendices

I am trying to put a long table in an Appendix. The appendix must meet following things.

The appendix should appear as:

Appendix A: Title 1

Appendix B: Title 2

Appendix 3: Title 3

The tables in the appendix should be numbered as follows:

Table A1: Title of Table A1 (if it is in appendix A)

Table A2: Title of Table A2 (if it is still in appendix A)

Table B1: Title of Table A2 (if it is still in appendix B)

The appendix should also start from a new page after the references.

I am using the following codes here.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside]{article}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage[para]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{longtable,booktabs,array}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

\begin{document}
\appendix
\section{Pre-Treatment Covariates}
\label{c} 

     \begin{longtable}{
             l
             >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{4.5cm}
             >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{4.5cm}}%????[ \centering
         \caption{Pre-Treatment Covariates for Calculating Propensity Scores\label{tab:covariates}}\\
         \toprule
         \textbf{Acronym} & \textbf{Variable Name} & \textbf{Description}                              
         \endfirsthead
         \multicolumn{3}{c}%
         {{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}}\\
         \textbf{Acronym} & \textbf{Variable Name} & \textbf{Description}
         \endhead
         \multicolumn{3}{r}{{Continued on next page}} \\
         \endfoot
         \endlastfoot
         \midrule
         \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{DETERMINANTS OF SMS ISSUANCE }} \\
         \midrule
         \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{Credit Risk}} \\
         \midrule
         RWATA & Risk Weighted Asset Ratio  & Risk Weighted Assets / Total Assets \\
         LLP   & Loan Impairment  & Loan Impairment Charges / Gross Loans  \\
         NPLs  & Non-Performing Loans & NPLS / Total Loans  \\
        LLP   & Loan Loss Provision  & Loan Loss Provision / Total Loans  \\
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{Profitability }} \\
        \midrule
        NIM   & Net Interest Margin & Net Interest Income / Total Earning Assets \\
        ROA   & Return on Assets & Operating Income / Total Assets  \\
        ROE   & Return on Equity & Net Income / Total Equity  \\
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{Funding Structure and Cost }} \\
        \midrule
        LFD   & Loans Funded by Deposits  & Loans / Customer Deposits\% \\
        FTD   & Funding Through Deposits  & Customer Deposits / Total Funding excel Derivatives\% \\
        LFST  & Loans Funded by Short Term Funding  & Net Loans / Short Term Funding  \\
         LFLT  & Loans Funded by Long Term Funding  & Net Loans / Long Term Funding  \\
         FCTL  & Funding Cost for Total Liabilities  & Total Interest Expense / Total Liabilities  \\
         FCTD  & Funding Cost for Total Deposits  & Interest Expense on Deposits / Total Deposits  \\
         \midrule
         \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{Liquidity }} \\
         \midrule
         LAFST & Liquid Assets Funded by Short Term Funding  & Liquid Assets / Short Term Funding \\
         LAFLT & Liquid Assets Funded by Long Term Funding  & Liquid Assets / Long Term Funding \\
         Liq. R & Liquidity Ratio  & Cash + Securities / Total Assets \\
         \midrule
         \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{Capital Ratios}} \\
         \midrule
         ER    & Equity Ratio  & Total Equity / Total Assets \\
         CAR   & Capital Adequacy Ratio  & (Tier 1 Capital + Tier 2 Capital) / Risk Weighted Assets \\
         \midrule
         \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{LOAN PORTFOLIO}} \\
         \midrule
         LBR   & Loans to Banks  & Loans to Banks / Total Loans  \\
         RMLR  & Residential Mortgage Loans Ratio & Residential Mortgage Loans / Total Loans  \\
         OMLR  & Other Mortgage Loan Ratio & Other Mortgage Loan / Total Loans  \\
         CRLR  & Consumer \& Retails Loans Ratio & Consumer \& Retails Loans / Total Loans  \\
         CCLR  & Corporate \& Commercial Loans Ratio & Corporate \& Commercial Loans / Total Loans  \\
         OLR   & Other Loans Ratio & Other Loans Ratio / Total Loans  \\
         LR    & Loan Ratio  & Total Loans / Total Assets \\
         \midrule
         \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{INSTITUTIONAL CHARACTERISTICS }} \\
         \midrule
         \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{Income and Cost Structure }} \\
         \midrule
         C/I   & Cost / Income & Operating Cost / Operating Income   \\
         LInc.R & Loan Income Ratio  & Interest Income on Loan / Total Loans  \\
         LIR   & Loan Interest Ratio  & Interest Income on Loans / Total Interest Income  \\
         OIR   & Other Interest Ratio  & Other Interest Income / Total Interest Income  \\
         IEDR  & Interest Expense on Deposits Ratio  & Interest Expense on Deposits / Total Interest Expense  \\
         OIER  & Other Interest Expense Ratio  & Other Interest Expense / Total Interest Expense  \\
         \midrule
         \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{Solvency }} \\
         \midrule
         D/E   & Debt to Equity Ratio & Total Liabilities / Total Equity  \\
         D/A   & Debt to Assets Ratio & Total Liabilities / Total Assets \\
         ICR   & Interest Coverage Ratio & EBIT / Total Interest Expense  \\
         \midrule
         \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{Other Institutional Characteristics }} \\
         \midrule
         AG    & Assets Growth  & Growth of Total Assets\% \\
         LG    & Loan Growth  & Growth of Gross Loans\% \\
         DPO   & Dividend Payout  & Total Dividends Paid / Net Income  \\
         Size  & Size of Bank  & Ln (Total Assets) \\
         Rep   & Reputation of Bank  & Letter of Guarantees / Total Assets \\
         COR   & Charge Off Ratio & Net Charge Offs / Total Loans  \\
         \bottomrule
     \end{longtable}%
     \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you use `article` document class, you need to manually set new page for `appendix` and for sections in it. Also you need to change `\thetable` which care for table numbering.

In MWE below I change your MWE: (i) for table I use `ltablex` package`which "join" features of`longtable`and`taqbularx`. See, if the following MWE is acceptable to you:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside]{article}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,longtable,tabularx}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

\usepackage{ltablex}% <-- added
\usepackage[margin=30mm]{geometry}% <-- added
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}


\begin{document}

\section{main text}
\begin{table}
\caption{table in main text}
\end{table}

\clearpage% <-- added
\appendix
\let\oldthesection\thesection% <-- added
\renewcommand\thetable{\oldthesection\arabic{table}}% <-- added
\renewcommand\thesection{Appendix \Alph{section}}   % <-- added
\setcounter{table}{0}        % <-- added

\section{Pre-Treatment Covariates}
    \label{c}

{\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X
                              >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\caption{Pre-Treatment Covariates for Calculating Propensity Scores}
\label{tab:covariates}\\
    \toprule
\textbf{Acronym} & \textbf{Variable Name} & \textbf{Description}
\endfirsthead
\caption{-- continued from previous page}\\
    \toprule
\textbf{Acronym} & \textbf{Variable Name} & \textbf{Description}
\endhead
    \bottomrule
\multicolumn{3}{r}{{Continued on next page}} \\
\endfoot
    \bottomrule
\endlastfoot
    \midrule
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{DETERMINANTS OF SMS ISSUANCE }} \\
    \midrule
\multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{Credit Risk}} \\
    \midrule
RWATA & Risk Weighted Asset Ratio  & Risk Weighted Assets / Total Assets \\
LLP   & Loan Impairment  & Loan Impairment Charges / Gross Loans  \\
NPLs  & Non-Performing Loans & NPLS / Total Loans  \\
LLP   & Loan Loss Provision  & Loan Loss Provision / Total Loans  \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{Profitability }} \\
\midrule
NIM   & Net Interest Margin & Net Interest Income / Total Earning Assets \\
ROA   & Return on Assets & Operating Income / Total Assets  \\
ROE   & Return on Equity & Net Income / Total Equity  \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{Funding Structure and Cost }} \\
\midrule
LFD   & Loans Funded by Deposits  & Loans / Customer Deposits\% \\
FTD   & Funding Through Deposits  & Customer Deposits / Total Funding excel Derivatives\% \\
LFST  & Loans Funded by Short Term Funding  & Net Loans / Short Term Funding  \\
LFLT  & Loans Funded by Long Term Funding  & Net Loans / Long Term Funding  \\
FCTL  & Funding Cost for Total Liabilities  & Total Interest Expense / Total Liabilities  \\
FCTD  & Funding Cost for Total Deposits  & Interest Expense on Deposits / Total Deposits  \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{Liquidity }} \\
\midrule
LAFST & Liquid Assets Funded by Short Term Funding  & Liquid Assets / Short Term Funding \\
LAFLT & Liquid Assets Funded by Long Term Funding  & Liquid Assets / Long Term Funding \\
Liq. R & Liquidity Ratio  & Cash + Securities / Total Assets \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{Capital Ratios}} \\
\midrule
ER    & Equity Ratio  & Total Equity / Total Assets \\
CAR   & Capital Adequacy Ratio  & (Tier 1 Capital + Tier 2 Capital) / Risk Weighted Assets \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{LOAN PORTFOLIO}} \\
\midrule
LBR   & Loans to Banks  & Loans to Banks / Total Loans  \\
RMLR  & Residential Mortgage Loans Ratio & Residential Mortgage Loans / Total Loans  \\
OMLR  & Other Mortgage Loan Ratio & Other Mortgage Loan / Total Loans  \\
CRLR  & Consumer \& Retails Loans Ratio & Consumer \& Retails Loans / Total Loans  \\
CCLR  & Corporate \& Commercial Loans Ratio & Corporate \& Commercial Loans / Total Loans  \\
OLR   & Other Loans Ratio & Other Loans Ratio / Total Loans  \\
LR    & Loan Ratio  & Total Loans / Total Assets \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{INSTITUTIONAL CHARACTERISTICS }} \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{Income and Cost Structure }} \\
\midrule
C/I   & Cost / Income & Operating Cost / Operating Income   \\
LInc.R & Loan Income Ratio  & Interest Income on Loan / Total Loans  \\
LIR   & Loan Interest Ratio  & Interest Income on Loans / Total Interest Income  \\
OIR   & Other Interest Ratio  & Other Interest Income / Total Interest Income  \\
IEDR  & Interest Expense on Deposits Ratio  & Interest Expense on Deposits / Total Interest Expense  \\
OIER  & Other Interest Expense Ratio  & Other Interest Expense / Total Interest Expense  \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{Solvency }} \\
\midrule
D/E   & Debt to Equity Ratio & Total Liabilities / Total Equity  \\
D/A   & Debt to Assets Ratio & Total Liabilities / Total Assets \\
ICR   & Interest Coverage Ratio & EBIT / Total Interest Expense  \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{Other Institutional Characteristics }} \\
\midrule
AG    & Assets Growth  & Growth of Total Assets\% \\
LG    & Loan Growth  & Growth of Gross Loans\% \\
DPO   & Dividend Payout  & Total Dividends Paid / Net Income  \\
Size  & Size of Bank  & Ln (Total Assets) \\
Rep   & Reputation of Bank  & Letter of Guarantees / Total Assets \\
COR   & Charge Off Ratio & Net Charge Offs / Total Loans 
\end{tabularx}
}

\begin{table}[htb]
\caption{table in main text}
\end{table}

\clearpage
\section{Pre-Treatment Covariates}
\setcounter{table}{0}% <-- added
\begin{table}[htb]
\caption{table in main text}
\end{table}
     \end{document}
```

**Edit:**
to MWE is added (rude) solution regarding section numbering. The solution suppose, that in appendix will not be subsections.

**Edit (2):**
I change the tables numbering in appendix such, that it start with `A1`, and further is continuous regardless to sections: `A2`, `B3` etc.

Note: this numbering is (to my opinion) at least misleading. If I see table `B3` than I expect that somewhere exist table `B1` and `B2` ...

[image]

Comment: thank you. It worked great but still the word appendix does not appear before the appendix number.

Comment: This wasn't clear to me, I focused more on table/section issues. I will look what I can do.

Comment: @AhmedArif, see edit of my question. I hope that it now cover all your requests.

Comment: The number of table in appendix A is Table A1 but in appendix B first table appears as Table B2 instead of Table B1.

Comment: this I didn't figured out from your question ... than you need to delete `\setcounter{table}{0}` after sections "B", "C" (if exist) etc.

Comment: If I delete `\setcounter{table}{0}` then table numbering start continuously from the main document. Like Table A9 for first table in appendix and so on.

Comment: Well, I say that you delete after second section in appendix. At least I understand you, that you like to have continuous numbering in appendix. well I will edit my answer.